# centos 5.5 , yum remove yum now can not install back

Tags: linux, centos, redhat

Here i am useing:

```
Centos 5.5
```

by mistake i did

```
yum remove yum
```

now i want to reinstall tried many ways not worked

i have tried.

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/gmp-4.1.4-10.el5.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/readline-5.1-3.el5.x86_64.rpm 
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-2.4.3-44.el5.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.12.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/libxml2-python-2.6.26-2.1.12.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/expat-1.95.8-8.3.el5_5.3.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/sqlite-3.3.6-5.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-sqlite-1.1.7-1.2.1.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/elfutils-libelf-0.137-3.el5.x86_64.rpm
rpm --nodeps -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/elfutils-0.137-3.el5.x86_64.rpm
rpm --nodeps -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/rpm-4.4.2.3-22.el5.x86_64.rpm
rpm --nodeps -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/rpm-python-4.4.2.3-22.el5.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/m2crypto-0.16-8.el5.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-urlgrabber-3.1.0-6.el5.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-3.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-iniparse-0.2.3-4.el5.noarch.rpm
rpm --nodeps -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/yum-fastestmirror-1.1.16-16.el5.centos.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/yum-3.2.22-37.el5.centos.noarch.rpm
yum -y update
```

not working ....
result
***-bash: /usr/bin/yum: No such file or directory***

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention if you got any errors when you ran the commands above, but I replicated your issue by doing a fresh install of CentOS 5.5 and doing "yum erase yum".  This also erased the packages "yum-fastestmirror" and "yum-updatesd" as dependencies.

Then, I did the following:

```
# wget http://mirror.symnds.com/distributions/CentOS-vault/5.5/os/x86_64/CentOS/yum-3.2.22-26.el5.centos.noarch.rpm
# wget http://mirror.symnds.com/distributions/CentOS-vault/5.5/os/x86_64/CentOS/yum-fastestmirror-1.1.16-14.el5.centos.1.noarch.rpm
# rpm -Uvh *.rpm
```

(Feel free to use your favorite mirror of vault.centos.org as you like, if you don't want to use the one I used....)

This put "yum" back (it needs "yum-fastestmirror" as a dependency, and "yum-fastestmirror" depends on "yum", so this was the quickest way I could think of to reinstall both at the same time).

After that, "yum" was working, and I was able to use "yum -y update" (which effectively upgraded the system to CentOS 5.10).